# Unix text processing to copy part of line in the same line

Tags: unix, awk, sed

[Edited]
I have a file with lines of the form:

```
codeToError[resources.ErrUndefined] = fmt.Errorf("1000: random string")
```

that I want to convert to:

```
codeToError[resources.ErrUndefined] = fmt.Errorf("%d: random string", resources.ErrUndefined)
```

Basically, for each line in the file, I need to copy part of the line to another place on the same line in the file and replace the numbers on the RHS with %d. I obviously dont want to copy paste hundereds of lines. I know "sed" or "awk" may help but was not sure how.

Comment: you really want to end up with three quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the numbers are represented as integers (including negative numbers),
please try the following:

```
sed -e 's/-\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}/%d/' -e 's/\([A-Za-z]\{1,\}\[\([A-Za-z]\{1,\}\)\].\{1,\}\)/\1, \2/' file
```

Result:

```
A[xyz] = "%d: random string", xyz
A[abcd] = "%d: another random string", abcd
A[bc] = "%d: random", bc
A[bcd] = "%d: random stuff", bcd
```

I'm afraid your expected output has inconsistent double quotes at the end
of lines, which I have omitted.
It will be easy to tweak the sed command above to meet your requirement,
or if you can fix your desired output, I'll update my answer accordingly.

**[EDIT]**

According to the updated example, please try the following:

With `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/-\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}/%d/' -e 's/\([A-Za-z]\{1,\}\[\([^]]\{1,\}\)\].\{1,\}\))/\1, \2)/' file
```

With `gawk`:

```
gawk '$0 = gensub("(\\w+\\[([^]]+)][^0-9-]+)-?[0-9]+(.+)\)", "\\1%d\\3, \\2)", 1)' file
```

With `Perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/(\w+\[(.+?)].+?)-?\d+(.+)\)/\1%d\3, \2)/' file
```

Result:

```
codeToError[resources.ErrUndefined] = fmt.Errorf("%d: random string", resources.ErrUndefined)
```

Hope this helps.